# How do I use or find documentation for robotiq_ft_sensor_acc numerical commands?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the kinetic-devel branch of the robotiq package and noticed that in the comments of rq_sensor.cpp, a "New interface with numerical commands" is mentioned in the `receiverCallback` function. Until now I've been unaware of these, as they don't seem to be mentioned anywhere except in the pull requests of the jade-devel branch of this package, which reference some old string-based commands like "SET ZRO". I am interested in using whatever the equivalent of "SET ZRO" is now to zero out my FT300 sensor before using its readings.

After some digging I've learned I need to use `rosservice call robotiq_ft_sensor_acc [command_id] [command]`, but as for what `[command_id]` and `[command]` should be, other than an integer and string respectively, I have no clue. I have tried every combination of numbers and strings but the service always returns `success: False` and either `res: !!binary |`  followed by some random short string of characters, or `res:''`. Also, occasionally the terminal running rq_sensor gives me a warning saying that I should use a numeric command instead of a string, something which the service doesn't seem to actually allow. It doesn't give this warning if I retry the same command a second time.

I'm very new to ROS so pardon me if this is a stupid question, but what commands are appropriate for this service? Or, where can I find documentation that tells me how robotiq_ft_sensor_acc is supposed to work?

Edit:

- Wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/robotiq
- Github: https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq
- robotiq_ft_sensor API: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robotiq_ft_sensor/html/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313833/how-do-i-use-or-find-documentation-for-robotiq_ft_sensor_acc-numerical-commands?/) by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-25**:
Can you please update your question with a link to the package that you are referring to?

**Comment by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on 2019-01-25**:
Yes! I've added everything I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaict, the constants to use with that service are -- as is often the case -- documented in the service definition itself ([this one](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/blob/78b0e4e76798092923a19f4e31b46a79619f0837/robotiq_ft_sensor/srv/sensor_accessor.srv)):

```
uint8 COMMAND_GET_SERIAL_NUMBER=1
uint8 COMMAND_GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION=2
uint8 COMMAND_GET_PRODUCTION_YEAR=4
uint8 COMMAND_SET_ZERO=8
uint8 command_id
string command  # deprecated, please use command_id with a value of COMMAND_*
---
bool success
string res
```

So legal values would seem to be: 1, 2, 4 and 8, corresponding to `GET_SERIAL_NUMBER`, `GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION`, `GET_PRODUCTION_YEAR` and `SET_ZERO` respectively.

The value of `command_id` is used in [this switch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/blob/78b0e4e76798092923a19f4e31b46a79619f0837/robotiq_ft_sensor/src/rq_sensor_state.cpp#L266-L283) to call the corresponding function.

> I am interested in using whatever the equivalent of "SET ZRO" is now to zero out my FT300 sensor before using its readings.

I'm not a Robotiq user myself, but iiuc, you'd have to use the value corresponding to `COMMAND_SET_ZERO` (ie: `8`) for that.

> After some digging I've learned I need to use rosservice call `robotiq_ft_sensor_acc [command_id] [command]`, [..]

As it's deprecated, you'd probably leave `command` (ie: the `string` field) empty.

And note that if you'd write a (short Python) service client, you'd actually use the *constant name*, not the value it maps to directly. See [robotiq_ft_sensor/nodes/rq_test_sensor.cpp](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/blob/78b0e4e76798092923a19f4e31b46a79619f0837/robotiq_ft_sensor/nodes/rq_test_sensor.cpp#L85) for a C++ example of how that would work.

---

Edit: the contants are also mentioned in the documentation of the [rq_state_get_command(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robotiq_ft_sensor/html/rq__sensor__state_8cpp.html#a1185f88d16bb9757cb33c46e63e60b0e) function.

That is all non-user-facing documentation though, so it would have been nice if this change had received a bit more attention -- perhaps in the form of an announcement somewhere in a Robotiq support/information channel.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on 2019-01-27**:
Thank you. I tried using those constants to no avail, and I'm pretty sure leaving the string field blank gave me another error, but I will try again on Monday and let you know what happens.

**Comment by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on 2019-01-31**:
I got a "not enough arguments" error by just passing `8` with no string.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:
Can you please edit your original post to show the exact command line you're trying to use? "no string" is not the same as "an empty string".

**Comment by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on 2019-01-31**:
Oh my gosh, I hadn't tried passing `8 ""`. That worked! Thank you!

**Comment by [praxidike74](https://answers.ros.org/users/40320/praxidike74/) on 2019-03-04**:
@mosslab Wow, I was stuck for almost an hour on this, (8, "") really worked, would have never came up with this by myself, thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:
The thing is: using the `8 ""` notation as arguments to `rosservice call` is only possible because `rosservice` provides that convenience.

If you'd tab-complete the `rosservice call`, you'd see that there are a nr of fields that need to be provided and they'll even be assigned their default ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:
.. values. For `string` fields, that would be an empty string (ie: `""`).

I would say that doing that would have made it immediately clear that those two arguments must be provided.